# Writing to custom timeseries with the Google Cloud Monitoring v3 api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

Google has warned that the v2 monitoring api is now deprecated and will be going away soon. However, migrating to v3 is proving to be a bit difficult. I'm trying to write a custom metric and am getting the following error responses:

Services > Google Monitoring API v3 > monitoring.projects.timeSeries.create

```
{
    "timeSeries": [{
        "metric": {
            "type": "custom.googleapis.com/test_metric",
            "labels": {
                "payment_type": "Paypal"
            }
        },
        "resource": {
            "type": "custom.googleapis.com/test_metric",
            "labels": {
                "payment_type": "Paypal"
            }
        },
        "metricKind": "GAUGE",
        "valueType": "INT64",
        "points": [{
            "interval": {
                "endTime": "2016-03-20T15:01:23.045123456Z",
                "startTime": "2016-03-20T15:01:23.045123456Z"
            },
            "value": {
                "int64Value": "2"
            }
        }]
    }]
}

{
  "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Field timeSeries[0].resource.type had an invalid value of \"custom.googleapis.com/test_metric\": Unrecognized resource name.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

The "resource" field is required, and docs say it's the "MonitoredResource"... but I don't see any api for creating one, only for listing. Taking a wild guess and setting it to "global" seems to get me a bit further and gives me this different error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Field timeSeries[0].resource.labels[0] had an invalid value of \"payment_type\": Unrecognized resource label.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

Listing the metric descriptors shows that payment_type exists:

Services > Google Monitoring API v3 > monitoring.projects.metricDescriptors.list

```
{
 "name": "projects/gearlaunch-hub-sandbox/metricDescriptors/custom.googleapis.com/test_metric",
 "labels": [
  {
   "key": "payment_type"
  }
 ],
 "metricKind": "GAUGE",
 "valueType": "INT64",
 "description": "Test",
 "type": "custom.googleapis.com/test_metric"
}
```

I've read through the migration guides and related docs, but am still stymied. Anyone know what I'm missing here?

**Update**: While it looks to be possible to get this working by removing "resource.labels" from the json, I'm still looking for a way to get this working via the java client api.

**Update 2**: The accepted (self answered) question shows how to do this with the java api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to use "resource" of "type": "global" but leave off "labels":

```
{
    "timeSeries": [{
        "metric": {
            "type": "custom.googleapis.com/test_metric",
            "labels": {
                "payment_type": "Paypal"
            }
        },
        "resource": {
            "type": "global"
        },
        "metricKind": "GAUGE",
        "valueType": "INT64",
        "points": [{
            "interval": {
                "endTime": "2016-03-23T01:01:23.045123456Z",
                "startTime": "2016-03-23T01:01:23.045123456Z"
            },
            "value": {
                "int64Value": "2"
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

This gives me a 200 OK response and adds the data to the time series.

This works from the api explorer directly. The equivalent code using java client api is:

```
public String writeCustomMetricValue(final String name, final Map<String, String> labels, final Long value) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(name);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(labels);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(value);

    final String now = DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString();

    final TimeInterval interval = new TimeInterval();
    interval.setStartTime(now);
    interval.setEndTime(now);

    final TypedValue pointValue = new TypedValue();
    pointValue.setInt64Value(value);

    final Point point = new Point();
    point.setInterval(interval);
    point.setValue(pointValue);

    final MonitoredResource resource = new MonitoredResource();
    resource.setType("global");

    final Metric metric = new Metric();
    metric.setType("custom.googleapis.com/" + name);

    final TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries();
    series.setMetric(metric);
    series.setPoints(Arrays.asList(point));
    series.setResource(resource);
    series.setMetricKind("GAUGE");

    final List<TimeSeries> timeseries = new ArrayList<>();
    timeseries.add(series);

    final CreateTimeSeriesRequest content = new CreateTimeSeriesRequest();
    content.setTimeSeries(timeseries);

    metric.setLabels(labels);

    try {
        return service().projects().timeSeries().create("projects/" + env.getProjectId().getId(), content).execute().toPrettyString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Name=" + name + ", labels=" + labels + ", value=" + value, e);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-monitoring</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev3-1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

When writing a data point, you must specify both the Metric and MonitoredResource to identify a unique time series. The |global| MonitoredResource has no labels, so it is already fully specified. It appears that your custom metric of type |custom.googleapis.com/test_metric| has a label named |payment_type|. In order to fully specify the Metric, you must assign a value to the |payment_type| field.

Try that and let me know how it works.

Comment: I'm still not clear if I should be using the global MonitoredResource in this case, but there doesn't seem to be an API for creating my own, and all the other existing ones produce errors when I try them. Adding this line inside the for loop in my other answer results in the same error response: metric.set(labelName, value);

Comment: Since you are migrating from v2, the |global| MonitoredResource type is the  most straightforward migration. v2 does not have the concept of MonitoredResource, so a basic translation should just be to global. If your metric corresponds to a resource in your virtualized cloud environment, you may wish to write to another (non-global) MonitoredResource type in the future. There is no API for creating a MonitoredResource; there is a curated list of MonitoredResource types that the API understands.

Comment: We looked into the error message you give. The Java client is munging the return value from the API in a way that makes it less useful. Can you print the request in text form? I still suspect that the problem is that your Java code is not setting metric.labels.payment_type.

Comment: My java code is just using the google provided client api. I'm not sure how to get the json text that the java api creates. I can step through the code in a debugger, but I can't find a good entry point that converts to a string to inspect. I suppose inspecting network traffic with wireshark or somesuch is an option, but was hoping I wouldn't have to go there.

Comment: Turns out that setting logging to the finest level causes the client code to output the json generated by the monitoring api. I think I'm close to a solution now that I can see what's being generated.

Comment: Ok I have a fix. I edited my answer and accepted it, so that answer should be a good working example now.

Comment: @PatrickEaton quick question Re: "There is no API for creating a MonitoredResource; there is a curated list of MonitoredResource types that the API understands." So even for custom metrics, there is no way to specify a custom label key/value pairs to write to?

Comment: @Devy, that is correct. There is still no support for custom MonitoredResources or adding custom labels to existing resource types. Rest assured, it has been logged as a feature request.