# Where user's Google Cloud Run metrics should be in Monitoring?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a service in Google Cloud Run and want to write some metrics to Google Cloud Monitoring.

Google Cloud Run seems to have separate resourse in Google Monitoring: [Cloud Run Revision](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_cloud_run_revision).

But unfortunately it is not available option of resourse type in Google Monitoring API.
You may receive this error using [Monitoring V3 library](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/monitoring/v3)

```golang
                Resource: &monitoredrespb.MonitoredResource{
                    Type: "cloud_run_revision",
                    Labels: map[string]string{
                        "service_name":  "my-service-name",
                        "revision_name": "my-revision-name",
                    },
                },
```

```
Failed to write time series data: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Metrics cannot be written to cloud_run_revision. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource for a list of writable resource types.
```

Should I write metrics to "Global" resouse type than?
But it looks like in this case, can't add revision_name nor service_name to Global resouse type:

```
Failed to write time series data: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Unrecognized resource label: service_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking on the response from [depsypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164939/writing-to-custom-timeseries-with-the-google-cloud-monitoring-v3-api), it can be done through java api. You can check the documentation for reference on what would be the equivalent code on java client api